# Inconsistent performance when writing pixels to custom buffer (X11 / C)

Tags: c, performance, buffer, render, x11

I'm writing my own library based on X11 which uses only CPU rendering (GPU usage is not allowed!).
Today I stumbled upon strange discovery. When I draw pixels like this:

```
const int ratio = 1;
for(int y = 0; y < XF_GetWindowHeight() / ratio; ++y)
    for(int x = 0; x < XF_GetWindowWidth() / ratio; ++x)
        XF_DrawPoint(x * ratio, y * ratio, 0xff0000); // function gets x, y and color
```

It completes after ~1.5ms every frame. But when I draw the same region but using fewer loop calls and drawing bigger rectangles instead of points (pixels) I get result of ~0.8ms.

```
const int ratio = 32;
for(int y = 0; y < XF_GetWindowHeight() / ratio; ++y)
    for(int x = 0; x < XF_GetWindowWidth() / ratio; ++x)
        // function gets x, y, w, h, color and if only draw outline (doesn't matter in this case)
        XF_DrawRect(x * ratio, y * ratio, ratio, ratio, 0xff0000, false);
```

It seems strange to me, that even if the XF_DrawRect function is more complicated and both loops in the end are drawing the same amount of pixels, calling fewer loops seems to impact the performance greatly.

**void XF_DrawPoint(int x, int y, uint32_t color)**

```
*(h_lines[y] + x) = color; // h_lines is array with pointers to each row
```

**void XF_DrawRect(int x, int y, int w, int h, uint32_t color, XF_Bool outline)**

```
uint32_t *s = h_lines[y] + x;
int hz_count = 0;

while(h--) {
    hz_count = w;

    while(hz_count--) {
        *s++ = color;
    }

    s += WINDOW_WIDTH - w;
}
```

So, as you can see, implementation of XF_DrawRect is more complex (there are some range checks at the beginning to trim the rectangle if it goes out of bounds, but it doesn't matter) then the XF_DrawPoint and still, there is ~2x improvement in speed, when drawing the same area.
My question is: **why?**

Comment: If `h` is 0, then the second can be faster. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @JérômeRichard h is never 0 at the beginning, because it is height of the rectangle. "x", "y", "w" and "h" are arguments passed to function. You can see in the example that I'm passing 32 (ratio) into the 4th parameter (which is this 'h'). I'm interested only in this example, when the first program is drawing each pixel one by one from left to right, top to bottom and the second is drawing rectangles every "ratio" pixels with "ratio" width and "ratio" height.

Comment: @JérômeRichard it would be hard to provide "minimal" example, because the library provides creating window, managing and handling events, and if I was to provide example written in bare x11 it would take 200-300 lines of code

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have added full definitions of functions, maybe it will help.

Comment: If `XF_DrawPoint` is not inlined that could explain the difference. For such a small function the overhead of a call is very significant (more expensive than what the function is doing).

Comment: @stepan Thanks, I think you are completely right! When I created another function "XF_DrawNoise" and done the filling using "h_lines" directly instead of calling thousands of functions, there was no such difference. But I don't really know how to make inline function, when I have header file with declaration, source file with definition and completely separated file with example project.

Comment: @stepan Extending my previous answer, I think I simply cannot. Because "h_lines" is defined in xf_system.c file and I don't want the user to be able to get access to h_lines directly, there's no way of inlining the function for other files to use. I suppose, it has to stay that way,  considering the fact that no one in their right mind would want to draw 640 * 480 separate pixels (at first the example was just generating random noise on the screen, to test fps count). Now I know that huge amount of function invokes can really slow down the program. Thank you!

Comment: Extending my extended answer: I was stupid back then... If I really wanted the end user of the library to draw each pixel separately as fast as possible, just hide the h_lines array in some .c file and make accessible helper function that will return it (so the user won't know about ugly h_lines variable and can just call GetFrameBuffer() function). Then the end user will have access to the framebuffer and will be able to draw to the screen pixel by pixel as fast as possible, and if he only wants to edit one or two pixels, he can still call DrawPixel function. Simple as that...